# Where can I get the constant values of the AD CA request submission in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, certificate

I am trying to learn to enroll a certificate request. When a request is submitted through ICertRequest.Submit method, it returns an integer with the following values.

CR_DISP_INCOMPLETE - Request did not complete,
CR_DISP_ERROR - Request failed
CR_DISP_DENIED - Request denied
CR_DISP_ISSUED - Certificate issued
CR_DISP_ISSUED_OUT_OF_BAND - Certificate issued separately
CR_DISP_UNDER_SUBMISSION - Request taken under submission

I want to use these values in my code. So I want to know how to access the definition of these constants in C#. A lot of examples related certificate request submission, I have seen, define these constants in their code itself. So is there a way to reference these constants from the CERTCLILib or CERTENROLLLib type libraries? I checked the object browser, but did not find these constants.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the list of constants in the certcli.h at [github](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/CertCli.h). I could pull whatever constants I needed so that I would have the exhaustive list of constants